# Sorting items in mutually exclusive lists in Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[image]I want to prompt a user to select some items in a list and based on that selection to generate a list of toggle buttons so that the items selected will be sorted in to separate lists to be used later in the workflow.

At first I tried to do this by already making 3 select boxes that have their values linked to the first selection box. This however didn't let me make the three lists mutually exclusive.

Any advice on how can I achieve this is in the jupyter notebook UI with the ipython widgets is appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your attempt to illustrate what you are trying to do.

Comment: Does the image provide a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
sorted_by = {
    "price": lambda item: item.price,
    "dispo": lambda item: item.metadata.disponibility
    # ... 
}
print(sorted(items, key=sorted_by['name']))
```

The advantages of my code is that you can add/edit a sorting function without affecting the rest.